# Java on Linux: maximize a non-Java GUI application

Tags: java, linux, user-interface, x11, signals

From Java code, is there a way to maximize the window of a different GUI application?  I have access to Process objects created for these other programs, as well as a semi-reliable way to get their PIDs and a generic String indicating the name of the process binary (e.g. "firefox").

I can also programmatically execute full bash shell statements (including commands connected with pipes), if there's some command-line way of going about it.

On MS Windows, I recall seeing somewhere about a Java library that wraps the win32 windowing API, allowing one to pass those Windows-specific signals to applications - would there be something similar to that on a Linux setup?  This is for a Red Hat system, if that matters.

Comment: Is this something X supports or will you also need to consider which window manager is running too ? I don't know how/if this matters, hence the comment.

Answer (score 4):

Not in a "standards-based" way, no.

The [X-Windows system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Window_System) is independent of specific window managers, as such, there is no standard way to "maximize" a window.  It ultimately depends on the features of the [window manager in use](http://xwinman.org/)...

Comment: Thanks.  This is for a RHEL 5.4 system using the GNOME package that comes with it, version 2.16.  From what I can gather, it looks like the window manager bundled with it is Metacity.  From that, I was able to google up wmctrl and will try it out.

Comment: wmctrl seems to work well for my situation.  For instance, an invocation of 'wmctrl -a firefox' will raise the window for firefox.  wmctrl can control EWMH/NetWM compatible window managers (which is quite a lot of them, it turns out) and in particular, will control the Metacity wm that is installed as default for GNOME on RHEL 5.4.  If you'd like to update your answer to reflect this, I can mark your answer as accepted, as it provided the clue for where to look for this info.

Comment: @weiji: I'm glad my answer helped point you in the right direction.  I recommend answering your own question with the information in your comment and accepting it as the answer; a simple "thanks to @maerics" or upvote is enough recognition for me =)